# Integration for special sine-function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I am having trouble integrating the following:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(t)\cdot t^{x-1} ~dt$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Does anybody know how that can be done. Ive tried to set it up with powerseries for $\sin(t)$, and by a substitution followed with integration by parts, non of that gave anything useful.

Does anybody know how to integrate this, using the gamma function?

Thanks

Comment: hint: use Gamma function

Comment: I tried that, could you be more specific?

Comment: *Hint 2.* For $0 < x < 1$ and $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 0$ with $z \neq 0$, we have $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{x-1} e^{-zt} \, dt = \frac{\Gamma(x)}{z^x}. $$

Comment: I don't know how to integrate complex functions

Comment: See also: [Generalized Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Generalization).

Comment: That can't be used, because x is not an integer!

Comment: When did anyone say $x$ was an integer?

Comment: Sorry, misread, I am just used to work with m being an integer, I found the solution.